# Jenkins Build job fails -revision check failed

Tags: svn, jenkins, build, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I'm receiving the below error from Monday. It was perfectly working fine without any issues last week. There were no changes done to the configuration. What could be the reason for this error here?

I've googled a bit and found this: http://www.codedisqus.com/CmVjPqeUge/issues-with-jenkins-and-svn-proxy.html , that's the exact scenario i'm facing. Except for a fact, i don't have any proxy between slave and master machines.

SvnKIT version: 1.5 ( but i don't think it has to do with SVN KIT version, since the latest once is 2.5 )

```
Started by user administrator
Building remotely on job1 in workspace C:\cc\checkout
Updating https://xxx.yyy.zzz.net/svn/repos/dev/trunk at revision '2015-06-17T11:19:41.167 +0530'
At revision 41457
hudson.util.IOException2: revision check failed on `enter code here`https://xxx.yyy.zzz.net/svn/repos/dev/trunk
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:178)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.run(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:113)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.calcChangeLog(SubversionSCM.java:654)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:815)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1270)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:609)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:531)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1718)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/repos/dev/trunk failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:388)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:361)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:707)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1020)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:180)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:118)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:148)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:160)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteLog.run(SvnRemoteLog.java:35)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1238)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:967)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNLogClient.doLog(SVNLogClient.java:872)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionChangeLogBuilder.buildModule(SubversionChangeLogBuilder.java:166)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /svn/repos/dev/trunk failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/dev/trunk'
svn: E175002: unknown host
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:777)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:382)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/svn/repos/dev//trunk'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:775)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: unknown host
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:517)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: xxx.yyy.zzz..net: unknown error
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:907)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1302)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1255)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1171)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1105)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1055)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createAddres(SVNSocketFactory.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:91)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:280)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:451)
    ... 30 more
Recording test results
ERROR: Publisher hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver aborted due to exception
hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did tests run? 


    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:178)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:146)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.<init>(TestResult.java:122)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:119)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser$ParseResultCallable.invoke(JUnitParser.java:93)
    at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2688)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:324)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:63)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at ......remote call to long1(Native Method)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1356)
    at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:221)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:752)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:978)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:967)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitParser.parseResult(JUnitParser.java:90)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.parse(JUnitResultArchiver.java:120)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.JUnitResultArchiver.perform(JUnitResultArchiver.java:137)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:74)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:721)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:183)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1743)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to click on the checkbox to always check out a fresh copy from subversion.

Comment: But, that would be an uncomfortable approach right? Let's say if the repository holds close to 40-100 gigs of code and if it's going to checkout a fresh copy again, the build results will go on forever. I'm wondering what could go wrong here.

Comment: and even this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16747622/issues-with-jenkins-and-svn-proxy. The error looks similar, but i dont have any proxies. Since the master and slave machines are in the same infrastructure and there are no proxies configured between them.

Comment: I remember seeing an error like this and that was my solution.  It shouldn't be checking out your entire repository though, just the project you are wanting to build.

Comment: if the Checkout strategy goes to 'Always checkout a fresh copy', it would always checkout a fresh copy as per the cron. If the strategy is update as much as possible, for each update to any files or adding new files, it will pick up the changes and update those specific files. Hmm, any other pointers?

Comment: Resolved it myself. Internet was not resolving in my jenkins machine. Copied the resolve.conf settings from another machine and re-checked it. It worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see UnknownHostException and Inet6AddressImpl... It is only guess, but could you try to use url with ipv4 address? something like http://123.55.66.77/repos/svn/trunk

If this will work, then try switch off IPv6 support for Java: [How to set java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882357/how-to-set-java-net-preferipv4stack-true-in-the-java-code)

==
Update:

I see you use https, so here can be problems with certificate if you use base IPv4 address, but at least error will look different.

Comment: Umm, I tried that. But still gives the same error. :(

Comment: Well, may be it is really proxy? Some forgotten settings... Check TortoiseSVN settings (it it installed), Subversion settings (%APPDATA%\Subversion) and finally try Wireshark to see if it try connect to unexpected hosts. Also, did you try connect to this URL via command line?

Comment: Yup. When i tried to run svn info on that repository from the machine. It listed the repository. I'll give it a shot with Wireshark.